# ImportError: cannot import name 'metadata' from 'importlib'

Tags: python, importerror, python-importlib

Under a python (`Python 3.7.5 (default, Oct 31 2019, 15:18:51) [MSC v.1916 64 bit (AMD64)] :: Anaconda, Inc. on win32`) session launched in an Anaconda prompt, I get the error

```
>>> import nbconvert
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\user1\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\jsonschema\__init__.py", line 31, in <module>
    from importlib import metadata
ImportError: cannot import name 'metadata' from 'importlib' (C:\Users\user1\Anaconda\lib\importlib\__init__.py)
```

Effectively, `metadata` is not in `importlib`

```
>>> import importlib
>>> dir(importlib)
['_RELOADING', '__all__', '__builtins__', '__cached__', '__doc__', '__file__', '__import__', '__loader__', '__name__', '__package__', '__path__', '__spec__', '_bootstrap', '_bootstrap_external', '_imp', '_r_long', '_w_long', 'abc', 'find_loader', 'import_module', 'invalidate_caches', 'machinery', 'reload', 'sys', 'types', 'util', 'warnings']
```

[This](https://github.com/pytest-dev/pytest/issues/5818) is the only reference I found, mentioning it was observed *in some cases* (weird?) in python 3.8.

---

**EDIT 1**:
I am now able to remove the error.
There is one change that does that: removing a string in the `PYTHONPATH` environment variable that led to an `OSError: [WinError 123] ...` after `>>> import nbconvert`.
Removing / adding that string, removes / reinstates the error.

I am not certain if the fact that I did `conda install nbconvert` in an activated virtualenv (where I have python 3.8.0) also played a role; I did not test before this install.

More importantly, I cannot figure out the connection between the `OSError` and the **presence of a line `from importlib import metadata`**.

---

**EDIT 2**:
I have a virtualenv with python 3.8.0, where `importlib` does not have `metadata` either.
So I still cannot figure out why the presence of a line `from importlib import metadata`.

```
C:\> conda activate opencv
C:\> conda list
...
importlib_metadata        1.1.0                    py38_0    defaults
...
nbconvert                 5.6.1                    py38_0    defaults
...
C:\> python
Python 3.8.0 (default, Nov  6 2019, 16:00:02) [MSC v.1916 64 bit (AMD64)] :: Anaconda, Inc. on win32
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import importlib
>>> dir(importlib)
['_RELOADING', '__all__', '__builtins__', '__cached__', '__doc__', '__file__', '__import__', '__loader__', '__name__', '__package__', '__path__', '__spec__', '_bootstrap', '_bootstrap_external', '_imp', '_pack_uint32', '_unpack_uint32', 'find_loader', 'import_module', 'invalidate_caches', 'reload', 'sys', 'types', 'warnings']
>>> import nbconvert
>>>
```

Comment: [*"This functionality is provisional and may deviate from the usual version semantics of the standard library"*](https://docs.python.org/3/library/importlib.metadata.html) - and it doesn't exist in 3.7 at all.

Comment: @jonrsharpe - See edited OP.
1) I cannot figure out why the presence of a line `from importlib import metadata`, in a distribution where `importlib` does not have `metadata`. It will evidently fail.
2) I have a virtualenv with python 3.8.0. Exactly the same happens, which is even stranger.
3) Strangely (for me) removing a troublesome string in `PYTHONPATH` removes the error (although it does not answer the two questions above).

Answer (score 16):

The issue was caused by a recent change in the library jsonschema. Looking at https://github.com/Julian/jsonschema/blob/master/jsonschema/init.py you'll see that there was a change on September 26, 2019 changing pkg_resources to importlib_metadata as a fallback for Python <3.8. However, this doesn't seem to work out of the box.

To fix the issue, you have to downgrade your jsonschema package to a version that predates the change:

```
pipenv install jsonschema==3.0.2
```

More information can be found here: https://blog.gaborschulz.com/my-jupyter-notebook-stopped-working.html

Comment: Thanks, worked perfectly.  If you're in Anaconda you can search for the package in "Environments", right-click, select "Mark for specific version installation", then pick 3.0.2.

Answer (score 11):

Today, I ran into an error similar (but not exactly the same) to yours.

Starting from Python 3.8, the `importlib` module has a `metadata` submodule. For libraries running under older Python versions, the library `importlib_metadata` has been made to replicate the behaviour. For example, the `jsonschema` library (used by Jupyter notebooks), uses it as follows:

```py
# __init__.py from jsonschema 3.2.0
try:
    from importlib import metadata
except ImportError: # for Python<3.8
    import importlib_metadata as metadata
__version__ = metadata.version("jsonschema")
```

To answer your first question, the cause of the error is most likely due to a mismatch in the versions of the installed libraries you were using. This could a result of manual pip installs or perhaps other libraries failing to list proper dependency versions.

Your second question (edit 1): importing `nbconvert` triggers the import of `jsonschema`, which will lead to the same error.

You also mention an OSError, but don't give any details when/how it occurred. In my original problem (how I found your question), I found that the `importlib_metadata` library could throw an OSError when some user folders are not accessible due to permissions. They fixed this in version 1.4.

Your last question (edit 2): you are using `dir()`, which lists the attributes of `importlib`, however, `importlib.metadata` is a valid module that is simply not listed as an attribute. It can be imported in python 3.8:

```
Python 3.8.1 (default, Jan  8 2020, 15:55:49) [MSC v.1916 64 bit (AMD64)] :: Anaconda, Inc. on win32
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> dir('importlib')
['__add__', '__class__', '__contains__', '__delattr__', '__dir__', '__doc__', '__eq__', '__format__', '__ge__', '__getattribute__', '__getitem__', '__getnewargs__', '__gt__', '__hash__', '__init__', '__init_subclass__', '__iter__', '__le__', '__len__', '__lt__', '__mod__', '__mul__', '__ne__', '__new__', '__reduce__', '__reduce_ex__', '__repr__', '__rmod__', '__rmul__', '__setattr__', '__sizeof__', '__str__', '__subclasshook__', 'capitalize', 'casefold', 'center', 'count', 'encode', 'endswith', 'expandtabs', 'find', 'format', 'format_map', 'index', 'isalnum', 'isalpha', 'isascii', 'isdecimal', 'isdigit', 'isidentifier', 'islower', 'isnumeric', 'isprintable', 'isspace', 'istitle', 'isupper', 'join', 'ljust', 'lower', 'lstrip', 'maketrans', 'partition', 'replace', 'rfind', 'rindex', 'rjust', 'rpartition', 'rsplit', 'rstrip', 'split', 'splitlines', 'startswith', 'strip', 'swapcase', 'title', 'translate', 'upper', 'zfill']
>>> from importlib import metadata
>>> dir(metadata)
['ConfigParser', 'Distribution', 'DistributionFinder', 'EntryPoint', 'FileHash', 'MetaPathFinder', 'MetadataPathFinder', 'PackageNotFoundError', 'PackagePath', 'PathDistribution', '__all__', '__builtins__', '__cached__', '__doc__', '__file__', '__loader__', '__name__', '__package__', '__spec__', 'abc', 'collections', 'csv', 'distribution', 'distributions', 'email', 'entry_points', 'files', 'functools', 'import_module', 'io', 'itertools', 'metadata', 'operator', 'os', 'pathlib', 're', 'requires', 'starmap', 'suppress', 'sys', 'version', 'zipfile']
>>>
```

Answer (score 3):

how is it going?

I fixed this error using the code:

```
conda install -c anaconda importlib-metadata
```

I got it from here: [codenong](https://www.codenong.com/cs109450515/)

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue of json schema while launching the jyputer notebook. Indeed this issue is owing to the lastest update in jsonschema. By downgrading the jsonshema to 3.0.2 the error `ImportError: cannot import name 'metadata' from 'importlib`' resolved and finally the jyputer notebook and jyputer lab launched.

Answer (score 0):

If there are no other syntax or dependency errors lurking in your environment and you want to maintain package versions as they are, you can try:

```py
import importlib
import importlib_metadata as metadata
importlib.metadata = metadata
import nbconvert
```

See a similar approach to a Word2Vec ImportError [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66405373).