# cannot import name 'open' from 'smart_open'

Tags: deep-learning, nlp, importerror, gensim

I was doing this and got this error :

```
from gensim.models import Word2Vec

ImportError: cannot import name 'open' from 'smart_open' (C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\smart_open\__init__.py)
```

Then I did this :

```
import smart_open
dir(smart_open)

['BZ2File','BytesIO','DEFAULT_ERRORS','IS_PY2','P','PATHLIB_SUPPORT','SSLError','SYSTEM_ENCODING','Uri','__builtins__','__cached__','__doc__','__file__','__loader__','__name__','__package__','__path__','__spec__','boto','codecs','collections','gzip','hdfs','http','importlib','io','logger','logging','os','pathlib','pathlib_module','requests','s3','s3_iter_bucket','six','smart_open','smart_open_hdfs','smart_open_http','smart_open_lib','smart_open_s3','smart_open_webhdfs','sys','urlparse','urlsplit','warnings','webhdfs']
```

As you can see there is no 'open' in it so how should I solve this. I tried to install different versions
and I upgraded all version too.

Answer (score 27):

I also got the same error. I resolved it by updating the smart_open to version 2.0.0.

conda install smart_open==2.0.0

or

pip install smart_open==2.0.0.

Answer (score 10):

```
import smart_open
smart_open.open = smart_open.smart_open
from gensim.models import Word2Vec
```

Works well.

Comment: This worked for me.

Answer (score 4):

I got the same error, and I solved this error by upgrading the smart_open to the latest version:

`conda update smart_open`

or

`pip install --upgrade smart_open`

Answer (score 2):

```
\lib\site-packages\gensim\utils.py in <module>
     43 from six.moves import range
     44 
---> 45 from smart_open import open
     46 
     47 from multiprocessing import cpu_count

ImportError: cannot import name 'open'
```

Same issue for me with smart_open 2.1.0 and gensim 3.8.3. Also after down and upgrading.

Answer (score 1):

In C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\gensim\utils.py, I simply changed `from smart_open import open` to `from smart_open import smart_open` and it worked.

Answer (score 1):

got the same problem.

in `gensim/utils.py:`

**change:**

```
from smart_open import open
```

**to:**

```
from smart_open import open
```

then **replace** `open` with `smart_open` in the file, reason:

seems that `smart_open` change the function name from open to `smart_open`

Comment: It looks like you said that we should change a line to . . . a 100% identical line.

Answer (score 0):

Start with

```
conda update smart_open
```

if it doesn't work go to `gensim/utils.py`

and replace

```
from smart_open import open
```

to

```
from smart_open import open
```

Comment: I think you forget to change the ___ to ___ line.